# Is it necessary to write all html meta tags in all php pages?

Tags: php, html

Is it necessary to write html tags for every page in php or we can write this in header section or include that header file in every page.

Comment: make header.php and include it every time

Comment: Think about it. What is the difference between including and writing something? Nothing. It's the same result

Comment: the concept is about reuse of code @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

create a file header.php and include all links in it.You can include those links by simply calling include or require php function.Consider the below example

`<?php
 include('header.php');
 ?>`

Answer (score 0):

links.php

```
<?php
$link='<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';

?>
```

you can include the links in every php file like

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
include_once 'links.php';
echo $link;
?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```